# Click event on glypicon

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-click

How do I add a ng-click event to a bootstrap glyphicon in a textbox? The event doesn't get fired...

```
<body ng-app ng-init="mymodel='THIS IS MY MODEL'">
    <h3>How to clear the model on remove icon click?</h3>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mymodel"/>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" 
       ng-show="mymodel" ng-click="mymodel = null"></i>
     </div>
    <p>This is my model: {{mymodel}}</p>

    <strong ng-click="mymodel = null">This works tho...</strong>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/58DY7rCpvAvrEDCFjMnS?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because glyphicons provided with " pointer-events: none;" as default you can override it and remove this functionality by simple CSS:-)

```
 .my .glyphicon {
      pointer-events: all;
    }

<div class="form-group has-feedback my" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mymodel"/>
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" 
       ng-show="mymodel" ng-click="mymodel = null"></i>
     </div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aj7GoX4Z2YNmDCJAGX7b?p=preview)

Comment: @Manube this is applying to glyphicon because of .form-control class and the idea is to show the input and glyphicon as a single entity.