# Get the onclick from Glyphicon inside EditorFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I was wondering whether there is any way to trigger the 'click' event of the EditorFor when I press on (or around) the glyphicon icon?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<span style="font-size:1.5em;" id="f1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign  form-control-feedback"></span>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok just found the answer it really helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047573/click-event-on-glypicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give an id to the EditorFor:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "e1" } })
    <span style="font-size:1.5em;" id="f1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign  form-control-feedback"></span>
```

And then use jQuery as follows:

```
$("#f1").bind("click", (function () {
    $("#e1").trigger("click");  
}));
```